# How to add version number to custom kernel and rootfs?

Tags: linux-kernel, version

I have a small embedded project where I had to make some minor tweaks to a linux kernel to support different hardware and minor tweaks to a debian-based operating system (my rootfs).

```
uname -a
```

no longer suffices to track these changes.  What can I do to add a version to these to track changes?  Create a small package that just `printf`s the version of the rootfs?  Figure out where uname source is and append my version to that?

Comment: One approach is to add a file and check that.